# Objects and Classes

Tags: objective-c

I come from a java background, I know how to call methods from objects but would the following be impossible?

```
main(){
     int v1=2;
     int v2=3:
     int sum;
     sum = [Add: (int) v1, (v2)];
}
add ((int) v1, (int) v2)){
    return v1+v2;
}
```

And my second question, How would I define a variable that is static throughout every instance of an object. For example, If i want the variable tax_rate to be .07 in every instance of an object.

Comment: You need to explain WHAT it is you want to accomplish, it is non-obvious from your source code snippet above.

Comment: This code as is won't work. You have no declaration of Add only add. There is no prototyping of add and you have no "methods" but only "functions" so you can't do `[Add: (int) v1, (v2)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are written and invoked a bit differently in Objective-C.  A method definition might look like this:

```
- (int)addThis:(int)v1 andThat:(int)v2
{
    return v1 + v2;
}
```

And you would invoke it like so:

```
int v1 = 2;
int v2 = 3;
int sum = [self addThis:v1 andThat:v2];
```

The syntax with the brackets is just for methods on objects (or classes).  If you're calling a plain old function, the syntax is the same as in C.